# RTL8812AE cannot connect to 5ghz networks

Tags: networking, wireless, 14.10, realtek

I recently purchased a PEX867WAC22 PCI-E wifi card from StarTech (RTL8812AE), and have not been able to connect to any 5 ghz network due to authentication timing out. The driver it comes with is only supported on Windows. It scans networks completely fine, and is able to connect to 2.4 ghz networks but not able to connect to 5 ghz ones. I am running Ubuntu 14.10 and kernel version 3.18. You can find my wireless information [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3amLE3mV). It's quite inconsistent if I can see my 5 ghz network or not, however usually I do (in that report it doesn't seem it's there though). This is the output when I try to connect to the 5 ghz network:

```
Apr 23 19:16:27 linux kernel: [ 1624.315511] wlan2: authenticate with 64:55:b1:e2:47:ff
Apr 23 19:16:27 linux kernel: [ 1624.316277] wlan2: direct probe to 64:55:b1:e2:47:ff (try 1/3)
Apr 23 19:16:27 linux kernel: [ 1624.519971] wlan2: direct probe to 64:55:b1:e2:47:ff (try 2/3)
Apr 23 19:16:28 linux kernel: [ 1624.723968] wlan2: direct probe to 64:55:b1:e2:47:ff (try 3/3)
Apr 23 19:16:28 linux kernel: [ 1624.927989] wlan2: authentication with 64:55:b1:e2:47:ff timed out
```

Comment: Good work using the [wireless scripts](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108). This line `parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)` or power saving settings might be related to your issue. Those ndiswrapper configs look suspicious. The dmesg output shows some history and details.

Comment: @GrantBowman I had this issue before I played with ndiswrapper to try to install my drivers. I'm not on a laptop so I don't think I have any power saving settings enabled; I haven't touched the disable_watchdog parameter either.

Comment: Why is the driver `ath9k` loaded? Is it declared in `/etc/modules` or what?

Comment: Having ath9k loaded was a silly mistake of mine, irrelevant.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, unable to authenticate on the 5ghz network.
`04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with my D-link DWA-582 (same Realtek chip), only I could not connect to any network.

I uninstalled the Ubuntu network-manager and installed wicd (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD) as I read somewhere some problems could be caused by the network manager.
This fixed the connectivity problems to both 2.4 and 5GHz, but speeds were limited to about 2Mbps, this was on Ubuntu 16.10 .

Then I installed the latest driver from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new (build with `make && sudo make install` and insert in kernel with `modprobe -v rtl8821ae`, notice: rtl88**21**ae not rtl88**12**ae). This raised speeds to 40Mbps (on 5GHz), which is consistent with the speeds from the Windows driver.

Note: I also installed the new kernel 4.9 somewhere during this, so I'm not sure whether installing the drivers from the github repo is really necessary.

Comment: It might be usefull to read: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed%20rtl8812ae