# 15.04 32 bit unstable wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek-wireless

So this has been a long time problem that I hoped would get fixed with some software updates.  My desktop machine has been having wireless connectivity problems since an update on 14.10 and now I have installed 15.04 and replaced the network adapter yet my problem remains.  Replacing the network adapter seemed to help but not completely resolve my problem.  I can connect to my wireless access point but the connection periodically just drops and I have to restart the computer to get it back.  Now for some basic info to help:

ifconfig

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:88:12:00  
      inet addr:10.0.0.3  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4cff:fe88:1200/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:97 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:9694 (9.6 KB)  TX bytes:13897 (13.8 KB)
```

iwconfig

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"MattWeb"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: E4:F4:C6:FB:35:89   
      Bit Rate=300 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:2   Missed beacon:0
```

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8812] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:6108]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Information added to the original post.

Comment: This question is related http://askubuntu.com/questions/645835/wifi-is-frequently-disconnecting

Comment: I had problems with my D-Link DWA-582 (uses the same RTL8812AE chip). Maybe this helps: http://askubuntu.com/a/870717/387404

Answer (score 0):

The kernel driver for this adapter is not very good.

There is a better driver from Realtek. You can install it this way

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

Then reboot.

Comment: Awesome I'll give that a try.

Comment: Well after giving this a try it doesn't seem to help my problem.  The connection still drops intermittently and requires a reboot to fix.

Comment: I suggest removing the driver and reporting but to launchpad. It looks that in my package the same kernel driver for this specific adapter as in kernel. There are fixes for other models.