# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS can view but cannot connect to 5Ghz wifi

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, realtek

My Ubuntu 14.04 LTS can view but cannot connect to home 5Ghz wifi. 2.5Ghz wifi works well. Wifi card should be good since the Windows 10 on the same machine works with both 5G and 2.5G

Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

Wireless script is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12794898/)

Is this a driver issue? or somehow the router is rejecting Ubuntu?

Any fix or insight is appreciated.

Comment: It seems to be a driver issue. See also [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/613136/rtl8812ae-cannot-connect-to-5ghz-networks )

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, see https://askubuntu.com/a/870717/387404
Regardless it is best to update to 16.04 when using new hardware

> I had similar problems with my D-link DWA-582 (same Realtek chip),
>   only I could not connect to any network.
>
> I uninstalled the Ubuntu network-manager and installed wicd (see
>   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD) as I read somewhere some
>   problems could be caused by the network manager. This fixed the
>   connectivity problems to both 2.4 and 5GHz, but speeds were limited to
>   about 2Mbps, this was on Ubuntu 16.10 .
>
> Then I installed the latest driver from
>   https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new (build with make && sudo make
>   install and insert in kernel with modprobe -v rtl8821ae, notice:
>   rtl8821ae not rtl8812ae). This raised speeds to 40Mbps (on 5GHz),
>   which is consistent with the speeds from the Windows driver.
>
> Note: I also installed the new kernel 4.9 somewhere during this, so
>   I'm not sure whether installing the drivers from the github repo is
>   really necessary.